# Convert subsets of a column to new dataframe rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to turn a dataframe column with unique identifiers into multiple rows (one row for each unique identifier)

Example:

```
V1    V2    Unique
5     12      1
10    15      1
20    35      1
40    50      2
60    70      2
100   50      2
```

What I need is:

```
row1 5 10 20
row2 40 60 100
```

Essentially I would like a row of V1 (ordering from left to right for first to last match) when Unique is the same (ignoring V2 entirely)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those always of same length? ie 3 in this case? otherwise you would be adding extra columns..or may be you want list or vector id that is of different length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example using `unstack` , if all groups have the same length:

```
t(unstack(dat[,c('V1','Unique')]))
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
X1    5   10   20
X2   40   60  100
```

Or if they don't have the same length, you can use `split`:

```
split(dat$V1,dat$Unique)
$`1`
[1]   5  10  20 100

$`2`
[1] 40 60
```

Comment: Works. They may or may not be the same length so this is great for either case. Thanks!